# The page control counts the current page again when you change the direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

```
images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"w8.JPG",@"w7.JPG",@"w6.JPG",@"w5.JPG",@"w4.JPG",@"w3.JPG", @"w2.JPG", @"w1.JPG" ,@"w9.JPG", nil];

self.pageControl.hidden = NO;
[self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:9];

UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
    if (pageController != 0 && imageIndex != 9) {
        [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:(pageController - 1)];
        pageController --;
        imageIndex++;
    }
    break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
    if (pageController <= 8 && pageController >= 0) {
        [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:pageController];
        pageController = pageController + 1;
        imageIndex--;
    }
    break;
    default:
    break;
}

imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] - 1): imageIndex % [images count];
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
```

When I start to swipe in a specific direction for example to the left, `page control's` dots change well, but if I change the direction, by first swipe the dot does not change, I have to swipe to the opposite direction twice so that the dot change. I found out that the page control counts the current dot again when you change the direction of tracking.

How can I change this default settings?

Comment: Post snippet of code you are trying so that one could understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try having page control be a static variable, so that it retains its value through the successive method calls when swiping left right left right etc.
I hope that helps.